# Is there a quicker way of doing this type of query (finding inactive accounts)?

Tags: sql-server

I have a very large table of wagering transactions. Let's say for the sake of the question I want to find the accounts of people who have wagered in the last year **but not** wagered in the last month,  so I do something like this...

```
--query one

select accountnumber into #wageredrecently from activity 
where _date >='2011-08-10' and transaction_type = 'Bet'
group by accountnumber

--query two

select accountnumber,firstname,lastname,email,sum(handle)
from activity a, customers c
where a.accountnumber = c.accountno
and transaction_type = 'Bet'

and _date >='2010-09-10'
and accountnumber not in (select * from #wageredrecently)
group by accountnumber,firstname,lastname,email
```

The problem is, this takes *ages* to get the data.  Is there a quicker way to acheive the same in sql?

Edit,  just to be specific about the time: It takes just over 3 minutes, which is far too long for a query that is destined for a php intranet page.

Edit (11/09/2011):  I've found out that the problem is the customers table.  It's actually a view.  It previously had good performance but now all of a sudden its performance is terrible,  a simple query on it takes almost as long as the above query pair.  I have therefore chosen an alternative table of customer data (that actually is a table, and not a view) and now the query pair takes about 15 seconds.

Comment: Run your query with include execution plan turned on to find where it's costly.

Comment: The second query takes about 96% of the total time (probably not unusual).  Over 3 minutes.  I just ran the second query without the first query and it's almost as long... so I guess my overal stackoverflow question is flawed because my problem is not the usage of both queries in this way but the second query being very slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question as the problem wasn't the structure of the query but one of the tables being used.  It was a view and its performance was terrible.  I change to an actual table with customer data in and reduced the execution time down to about 15 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to join `customers` after you have found and aggregated the rows from `activity` (I assume that `handle` is a column in `activity`).

```
select c.accountno, 
       c.firstname,
       c.lastname,
       c.email,
       a.sumhandle
from customers as c
  inner join (
                select accountnumber,
                       sum(handle) as sumhandle
                from activity
                where _date >= '2010-09-10' and
                      transaction_type = 'bet' and 
                      accountnumber not in (
                                              select accountnumber 
                                              from activity
                                              where _date >= '2011-08-10' and
                                                    transaction_type = 'bet'
                                           )
                group by accountnumber
             ) as a
    on c.accountno = a.accountnumber
```

I also included your first query as a sub-query instead. I'm not sure what that will do for performance. It could be better, it could be worse, you have to test on your data.

Comment: This takes longer,  but I have discovered that the problem is the customers view.  I've edited the original question to explain more.  Thanks for answering though.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your exact business need, but rarely will someone need access to innactive accounts over several months at a moments notice. Depending on when you pruge data, this may get worse.

You could create an [indexed view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933148%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx) that contains the last transaction date for each account:

> max(_date) as RecentTransaction

If this table gets too large, it could be partioned by year or month of the activity.

Comment: Except that `MAX` aggregate is not allowed in indexed views, as explained in the very article you link.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered adding an index on `_date` to the `activity` table? It's probably taking so long because it has to do a full table scan on that column when you're comparing the dates. Also, is `transaction_type` indexed as well? Otherwise, the other index wouldn't do you any good.

Comment: _Date is indexed, but transaction_type isn't. (I am not really the db admin so adding a new index isn't easy to do on a whim.. it is possible though)  I tried removing transaction_type from the query, but it still takes a long time to run.